# How to test update action?

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, functional-testing

I am trying to test my updateAction which allows to update my users in database but I don't know how I can test it... I have succed to test my createAction which add an user in my database. So I would like to get the user id which I have just created to udpdate this.

This is my function testCreate :

```
public function testCreate()
    {
        $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/admin/user/new');

        $buttonCrawlerNode = $crawler->selectButton('submit');

        $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form(array(
            'myapp_usertype[email]'            => 'testadd@gmail.fr',
            'myapp_usertype[role]'             => 'ROLE_USER',
            'myapp_usertype[password][first]'  => 'test',
            'myapp_usertype[password][second]' => 'test',
        ));

        $this->client->submit($form);
    }
```

Comment: You can use mocks initially to check the functionality works, with hard coded results.  This checks your code, not the actual interaction with the database. The next step might be to get a list of your users before the create (query and select them all), do the create, then get the new list.  You new number of entries in the list should be 1 greater than before, and the new ID should be present, with the email, role, and password you specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so dry, but you can try:

```
public function testUpdate()
{
    $user = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('YourUserBundle:User')->findOneByEmail('testadd@gmail.fr');

    $crawler = $client->request('GET', '/admin/user/edit/'.$user->getId());
    $form = $crawler->selectButton('submit')->form();

    $form = $buttonCrawlerNode->form(array(
        'myapp_usertype[email]'            => 'another@gmail.fr',
        'myapp_usertype[role]'             => 'ROLE_ANOTHER',
        'myapp_usertype[password][first]'  => 'test',
        'myapp_usertype[password][second]' => 'test',
        ));

        $crawler = $client->submit($form);

    $user = static::$kernel->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getRepository('YourUserBundle:User')->find($user->getId());

    $this->assertEquals(
        'another@gmail.fr',
        $user->getEmail()
    );

    $this->assertEquals(
        'ROLE_ANOTHER',
        $user->getRole()
    );
}
```